# get nearby location from coordinates to street address

Tags: php, jquery, google-maps-api-3, maps, street-address

I am working on a mobile website in which user has the option of getting the nearby locations. Now the I am getting the current location of the user through HTML 5 geolocation api which gives me its coordinates and I am displaying the result on map along with the all the locations in my database. Now, I want the data to be displayed in a list form along with distance from user's current location. Any ideas on how to do that.

PS
I have read the reverse geolocation api provided by google but their t&c states that i have to display the results on the map and not use it anywhere else.Plus they are also saying that geolocation api is discouraged on dynamic addresses.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Limits

Comment: Any specific country/region or worldwide?

Comment: worldwide is the plan but it will be probably used in india for now.

Comment: Not familiar with India, but I'm sure there are local Indian providers of lat/long to street address lookups... though probably requiring payment. Alternatively, OpenStreetMap might be an alternative to Google Maps, or MapQuest that uses OpenStreetMap data

Comment: So your actual question is how to retrieve the distance of locations from the user?

Comment: yeah i want to know the distance from the users current location to location stored in my database whose coordinates and adress i know.